# Javascript or server-sent events arn't loading instantly on php webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the problem that when I load my website or press a button, the css style of the buttons, which are set by the server-sent events and javascript, need some time to load. When you watch the [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/ZzhGb21Z2cA) you that when I press the second button and the website reloads the first button need some time to get the color set by server-sent events.

website:

```
    <?php
    shell_exec("gpio -g mode 23 out");
    shell_exec("gpio -g mode 24 out");
   
    if (isset($_POST['lampe1'])){
    $test = exec('gpio -g read 23');
        if($test==0){
            shell_exec("gpio -g write 23 1");
            //shell_exec("sudo python3 /var/www/html/gpio0.py");
        
        }else{
            shell_exec("gpio -g write 23 0");
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['lampe2'])){
    $test = exec('gpio -g read 24');
             //directory = /var/www/html
             //exec('touch test.txt');
        if($test==0){
            shell_exec("gpio -g write 24 1");
            //shell_exec("sudo python3 /var/www/html/gpio0.py");
        
        }else{
            shell_exec("gpio -g write 24 0");
        }
    }
    ?>


    <html>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var source = new EventSource("sse1.php");
            source.onmessage = function(event) {   
        if (event.data == 1){
        document.getElementById("lampe1").style.backgroundColor = "#faba03";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("lampe1").style.backgroundColor = "#18191A";
             }
        }
        var source = new EventSource("sse2.php");
            source.onmessage = function(event2) {   
        if (event2.data == 1){
        document.getElementById("lampe2").style.backgroundColor = "#faba03";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("lampe2").style.backgroundColor = "#18191A";
           }
        }   
        }
        
    </script>

    <body>

    <form method="post">   
    <button class="left" id="lampe1" name="lampe1" >lampe 1</button>
    <button class="right" id="lampe2" name="lampe2" >lampe 2</button>
    </form>

    </body>
    <style>
    body {
      background-color: #18191A;
        }
    button{
      font-family: lato,sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 70px;
      letter-spacing: 0.1em;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 30px 40px 30px 40px;
      position: relative;
      border: 3px solid #ffffff;
      border-radius: 60px;
      background-color: #18191A;  
      width: 49.5%;
        }
    .left{
            float: left; 
            margin-bottom: 10px; 
        }    
    .right{
           float: right;
           margin-bottom: 10px; 
            
        }
    </style>
    </html>
```

sse1.php: (sse2.php looks the same)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$onoff = exec('gpio -g read 23');
echo "data: " . $onoff . "\n\n";

@ob_flush();flush();
?>
```

Comment: That video tells nobody anything useful.

Comment: It shows that the button style does not load immediately when the website is opened.

Comment: Instead of running `exec` in PHP, can you just hardcode a value for debugging purposes to determine if the delay is caused by that execution. Also, you should inspect the connection itself, maybe there is some slowness from one of the handshakes? Also, you are binding on page load, but if you move the JS below you can immediately invoke those since the IDs will be available.

Comment: A hardcoded value isn't solving the problem. What do you mean by handshake? I don't know how to start the JS earlier...I tried document.ready stuff but than nothing worked anymore. @ChrisHaas

Comment: When debugging, I always try to remove complexity. By “isn’t solving the problem”, do you mean that you tried it, but it didn’t fix it, or do you mean “I need that code so I can’t remove it”.

Comment: As for the JS, you can’t call getElementById until the ID exists in the DOM. Onload is the safest way to guarantee that, but you can also place you JS physically below your form, and remove all of the onload stuff, just create your EventSource object.

Comment: For the handshake stuff, that includes DNS lookup, TCP connection and TLS handshake, see this for debugging: https://www.debugbear.com/blog/devtools-network

Comment: I tried all 3 advises now and none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

If fixet it with adding some php code :)

`<button class="left" id="lampe1" name="lampe1" style="<?php $status = exec('gpio -g read 23'); if($status==0){echo" background-color:#18191A;";}else{echo" background-color:#faba03;";}?>">lampe 1</button>`

the button now gets the right color on load